Hazar rate and fat tails
Let $F(x)$
and $f(x)$
be the CDF and PDF, respectively, of a random variable $x$
, and assume that $F(x)f(x)+x$
is strictly increasing in $x$
. Therefore, if I am not wrong, this includes a larger class of distributions than distributions with reverse hazard rate. Do you think this is correct?
Moreover, is $F(x)f(x)+x$
is strictly increasing in $x$
for the Pareto distribution? And for other distributions with fat tails?
Thanks!
